# wordpress upload form javascript help

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a custom template with custom admin panel, I have a image uploader using the wordpress media uploader in lightbox.

Here is the structure:

```
textbox 1 - browse 1
textbox 2 - browse 2
textbox 3 - browse 3
```

If I click on browse 1, the popup apears and if i click "insert into post" the lightbox media uploader will disappear and return a image url.

But the problem is the url appends n the 3 textbox and i only click on browse 1,. My expected result is if i click browse 1 it should be append in textbox 1 and so on.

Here is my code

```
jQuery('.op_upload_image_button').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).click(function() {
        formfield = jQuery(this).parent().find('.op_upload_image').attr('name');
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
        return false;
    });
    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
        jQuery('.op_upload_image').val(imgurl);
        tb_remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're after. Maybe you could try to explain step by step what you would like to happen (even if it doesn't currently).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure from the question, but I wonder if this is because all three of the textboxes are `.op_upload_image` and this bit `jQuery('.op_upload_image').val(imgurl);` is referencing the last textbox?

Comment: i use jQUery each so i can get specific area where to put the returned url. but how can i pass the variable from the click function to window.send_to_editor?

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.op_upload_image_button3').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).click(function() {
        formfield = jQuery(this).parent().find('.op_upload_image3').attr('name');
        tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
        return false;
    });

    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
        imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
        jQuery('.op_upload_image3').val(imgurl);
        tb_remove();
    }
});
```

Just change class name for button and text field class.